# Heatmap is upside down

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I have a point file saved as a shapefile, now I want to produce a heatmap of the values. However the heatmap is projected upside down. I suspect my y coordinates are inverted or negative but I do not know how to fix it. Can somebody help?

[image]

Comment: I'm ussing the 2.14.2 verssion and i found the same problem, i have a point file and i want to produce a heatmap in ESRI .hdr format, the raster file is projected upside down... So the bug is not fixed yet

Comment: Please don't post comments as answers, however valid.

Answer (score 2):

This issue could be related to the following bug: [Heatmap generated TIF with bad CRS](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12264). In that case, you either have to wait for/support a fix or use a different tool.

Comment: Well - that bug is already fixed, it's just waiting on 2.8.2 to be released. You can use the ltr-dev version in the meantime or wait for the formal release.

Comment: Good to hear that the issue is fixed @ndawson. Strange that the ticket is still open though ... Any idea why?

Comment: The issue with the display is fixed, but there's still something slightly wrong in how the heatmap plugin is creating the raster (eg GDAL gives odd metadata values).