# heatmap dislocated when generated

Tags: qgis, heat-map

QGIS 2.8.1
Does anyone have the answer to why a generated heatmap appears without coordinates and therefore is not on top of the vectorlayer that it was generated from? I checked the CRS setting but that should be okay. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: There is a (known) Bug with this in 2.8, but it works with 2.6.

Comment: Related (with comment info regarding bug): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139019/heatmap-is-upside-down

Comment: That might very well be the same problem then...Thanks @ChrisW